# want to show only calendar on my page which can select date range using angular,bootstrap

Tags: jquery, angular, bootstrap-4, calendar, date-range

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjp8M.png)I just want to show calendar which can select date range. I have tried using angular date range picker but in that case i am not able to display calendar always, calendar is displayed when i select icon. but i want to display only calendar and select date range from that. can anybody please help me out.

```
 <hr>
 <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
    <mat-date-range-input [rangePicker]="picker">
      <input matStartDate placeholder="Start date">
      <input matEndDate placeholder="End date">
    </mat-date-range-input>
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-date-range-picker #picker></mat-date-range-picker>
    

  <mat-error *ngIf="range.controls.start.hasError('matStartDateInvalid')">Invalid start date</mat-error>
  <mat-error *ngIf="range.controls.end.hasError('matEndDateInvalid')">Invalid end date</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
<p>Selected range: {{range.value | json}}</p>
```

Comment: I have created a stackblitz example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-obv7ds?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdate-range-picker-overview-example.ts

Comment: Hi Naman, Thanks for your help. But this is not compatible to angular 11

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-oga96t?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: thanks naman for you help . but can you please check the image i posted . actually i want to show calendar like that

Comment: That's just css though. You can manipulate CSS accordingly.

Comment: Hi naman , I am not able to have only calendar. It shows blank page for me. I have added my code to stackblitz example as well.https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-9x3rxa?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-c3maob?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts

Comment: in this it is asking for input, i am not having only calendar

Comment: I have done some changes as you suggested, but it show blank page.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-4fyabp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Even I am not sure why it's not working. Will look into it.

Comment: In `app.html` change `opened` to `[opened]`

Comment: Yes ! done Thanks a lot Naman Jain